# Show recursivity in swagger docs

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

If I declare `DepartmentDto` type that recursively references itself:

```
export class DepartmentDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty()
  id: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  parentDepartment: DepartmentDto;

  @Type(() => DepartmentDto)
  @ApiProperty({ type: DepartmentDto, isArray: true })
  subDepartments: DepartmentDto[];
}
```

I get this inside swagger docs:

```
[
  {
    "id": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "parentDepartment": "string",
    "subDepartments": [
      "string"
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a way to showcase recursivity in the docs using `@nestjs/swagger`?

Comment: One of the issue says use it like ```@ApiProperty({ type: (type) => DepartmentDto, isArray: true })
  subDepartments: DepartmentDto[];``` but it is not working for me. link=https://github.com/labibramadhan/swagger/pull/1

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found so far is:

```
export class DepartmentDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty()
  id: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  parentDepartment: DepartmentDto;

  @ApiProperty({ })
  subDepartments: DepartmentDtoNextlevel[];
}

export class DepartmentDtoNextlevel extends DepartmentDto {}
```

It will render in swagger at least one child, but at the end, an array of strings will appear inner it:

```
"subDepartments": [
      "string"
 ]
```

- the use of type: () => [DepartmentDtoNextlevel], didnt make difference.